# TV motherboard / LDVS and universal LED panel

Tags: hdmi, tv

On eBay you can find hundreds of Samsung (but also LG, Philips, etc.) Smart TV motherboards (see e.g. here https://www.ebay.com/itm/132373029756).

What I would like is to have more of those motherboards (e.g. 10) in a way I can connect them to some universal LED panel and control the selected motherboard with the standard IR remote control and be able to choose which Smart TV motherboard to use - for a start, 2 motherboards and selecting the right one by manually switching the cable is okay.

Is that possible? I'm quite a **layman**, but I am able to learn and I know electronics basics and I can solder and understand some tech documentation.

I found something called the Universal LVDS Signal Interface Converter (https://www.ebay.com/itm/224279813062), which could perhaps be used somehow as a bridge between the motherboard and some universal LED panel.

Can anyone advise and help me - not very technically ideally:) - how to do it and which LED panel to use?

I'd love to understand that, read about it and dig into it myself and test it. I am happy to share here my results.

Thanks

[image: My idea how it could work]

**Update**

First, thank you all answers, based on them I decided to update my initial question with more details and reasons behind my question:

- We are testing video (e.g. like Netflix, YT) and other apps on Smart TVs (Samsung, LG, Philips, Hisense, VIZIO, ... ).
- We have two options: Either to have 100 televisions in the office or, say, 10 LED panels and 100 motherboards that we will connect to them.
- It's not just a place in teslab and a price of TVs. It's also (and now mainly) about the fact that it is very hard to buy specific TV models older than 5-7 years, which we need for tests, but there are a tons of motherboards available on eBay.
- I do not need a single universal LED panel. It may be that there will be several LED panels taken from an existing TVs used for specific set of motherboards that will be connected to it, e.g. from one manufacturer or model line. However I have no idea how to find out which motherboard is compatible which which LED panel.
- I am ok to have the picture quality degraded, etc. What I need is to start the app, sign in/sign up, browse through it for 10 minutes, play single video. Test done.
- Switching the motherboard can be as simple as possible - I just connect one motherboard, test the app, disconnect it and connect another motherboard...
- Might be more clever ideas how to solve it (I have suggestion to convert the signal from motherboard to HDMI, but it sounds even crazier to me...).
- I am OK to make PoC and fail.

Comment: why do you want to do this? ... this appears to be an XY question ... asking about a perceived solution to an unspecified problem, instead of asking about the actual problem

Comment: @jsotola I have updated my question with more details. I should have done it when I asked. I am sorry for that.

Comment: now it makes sense ... maybe TV emulators are available

Comment: @jsotola There are simulators and also emulators, but it is like playing MS-DOS Stunts game and then going to the real race track. I am working in Smart TV dev for 15+ years you have to believe me this:)

Comment: I'm well aware that emulators do not fully exhibit the behavior of real hardware ... I mentioned emulators in case that you are just starting out

Comment: if you have a lot of time and money to throw at this, then maybe an FPGA based converter could be developed that would accept input from different motherboards and send the output to one panel

Answer (score 0):

There is no such thing as an universal LED panel.

So, no, that's not possible. Display interfaces are inherently very high speed and there's didn't ways to control panels, so that just plugging a different panel into an existing motherboard simply physically won't work out. Plus, with the signals being very high speed, it's impossible to simply add more cable and a switch.

Comment: Hello, thanks for answer, so even something close to my "idea" is not possible? What I wanted to achieve is having one LED panel and e.g. 10 motherboards instead of having 10 televisions. The switching is not mandatory. I am fine with plugging it all off and changing cables.

Comment: Not possible, as said. No such thing as a panel that works with multiple motherboards.

Comment: Thanks! I really appreciate your answer.

Answer (score 0):

> Is that possible?

Short answer, no.

---

Display interfaces are generally LVDS. LVDS is basically a high-speed, differential communication. For displays, as the resolution gets bigger more channels are required (e.g. 1 ch / 4 pairs for 720p, 2 channels / 8 pairs for 1080p, 8 channels / 32 pairs for 4K, etc). Although there are some multi-channel LVDS multiplexers and buffers which allows the designers to "duplicate" the LVDS lanes, it's not the only thing you'll require for your application (For higher resolutions you'll need more multiplexers which need to be perfectly synchronised). If your requirement was something like duplicating the image to multiple displays then the answer would be "yes", but switching sources (TV board/driver) or targets (display) doesn't seem to be possible, or at least easy to implement.

One problem is that some of the TV boards (and their firmware) are optimised for some particular displays and resolutions. Therefore the pinouts might be different which makes everything even more difficult. Also, some of them are able to detect display failure at power up. This will make source switching further more problematic, if the TV boards you plan to buy are one of those.

---

> I found something called the Universal LVDS Signal Interface Converter

This is not you are looking for or something you can use for your application. LVDS is a high-speed, multi-channel communication. For displays, as the resolution gets bigger more channels will be required. 20-pin interface is for single channel LVDS (e.g. 480p) and 40-pin interface is generally for dual channel LVDS (bigger than 1024x768 e.g. 1080p). But it's possible that some low-res displays accept 40-pin connector. So, this board is some sort of "connection adapter", nothing else.

Comment: Hello,

Thank you very much for the explanation. I kind of suspected that it would be a problem, but I naively hoped that there is a solution to have only motherboards and one LED panel instead of 10 televisions. Switching between TVs is not necessary, it is a bonus. I don't mind turning everything off and on again, but what's a problem is having places for 10 TVs plus older models are not available, but there are hundreds of motherboards on ebay.

The reason why I wanted it was to have an easier way to test applications on Smart TVs, and to save space in the lab.

Peter

Comment: @STeN now I understand your problem better. So, switching sources on-the-fly is not what you are looking for. Okay. But the concerns in the second paragraph still hold. Backlight is another issue that I forgot to mention.